# any option to create a legend with the dropdown button

Tags: javascript, jquery, d3.js

I am working on java script and d3 library. i am developing a graph using the combination of d3 and rickshaw. and the graph looks like this http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/3887051 . is there any option to put all the legend in drop down option so that it looks more precise. thanks in advance. any help would be appreciated.

Comment: What do you mean by 'drop down option'?

Comment: its like a legend which contains the graphs information in a dropdown format. like a link here http://code.shutterstock.com/rickshaw/examples/lines.html which has info on the bottom right arranged in one below the other (Tokyo, London & NewYork) i request a similar kind of solution where the legend is arranged in a dropdown list.